# dev environment for jade/haml, sass/stylus and coffee (maybe AMD) - nodejs

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, development-environment, pug, stylus

I've recently switched from jsfiddle to codepen.io - after a long look at all possiblities - and am enjoying it

I'd like to replicate a similar environment locally, building ideally jade/stylus/coffee, but equivalents of the first two are okay. Ideally Node.js based. Something like brunch.io is abstracted a little too far for my desires.

Well, ideally I'd like a SaaS IDE offering a Chocolat style environment and managing the file system and build process (know any?) but I can't think of anything ;-)

So, to bring it back to a question - does anyone know a starter kit, bundling together the appropriate node modules, a simple scaffold, and appropriate watch commands into one?

It's something I can build myself - but thought best to see if there is anything I can leverage.

... I might also have another plan with brunc

Comment: do you mean something like [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/index.html)?

Comment: I'd actually installed yeoman last week, but at a glance hadn't thought it would be appropriate. but now `actually RTFM` it does look good. ill have a play

Answer (score 1):

If you want something that looks like a CoffeeScript + Express template/starter-kit there are a few projects like [skeleton](https://github.com/EtienneLem/skeleton) and [express-coffee](https://github.com/twilson63/express-coffee). I recently put together [frappe](https://github.com/dweldon/frappe) which combines a few elements I liked from those projects. It contains a few basic routes and some sample code, to get you started.

Comment: thanks david. it does look good. i was hoping to test both your project and yeoman today but am currently giving cloud9 IDE a go and it's node 0.6.x and neither project will run. have to fire it up at home on the mac

Comment: out of interest, how does your project differ from, say, skeleton

Comment: That's a good question - they are pretty similar. Here are a few ways they are different: Skeleton actually creates a project, whereas frappe is just a template. In frappe, modules are auto-loaded to app.locals instead of app. To me this seems more clean and allows things like helpers to be directly available in views. Frappe has a few common convenience elements built in via the cakefile: a test harness (with port switching), automatic restarts, and package updating. The directory structures are a little different. Frappe keeps pretty much everything under the app directory.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. im going to have to find some time to install and test all of these. shame cloud9 has such an old version of node!